# Can Entity Framework create scripts to: Clear the database, Create the database from scratch

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

You can get EF to create a script to implement the latest migration. But is there a way to get it to:

1. Create a script to delete all tables, in the proper order, for a given migration snapshot
2. Create a script to build the database from scratch (after running the previous script)?

I ask because I have distinct databases for dev -> qa -> stage -> production. For each step except -> production, what would work best is to save off the scripts from the previous slot and then apply them at the next slot when migrating the code up.

And if there's a better/easier way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: _delete all tables_ - how about DROP DATABASE?

Comment: _build the database from scratch_ - remove all migrations - delete Migrations folder in solution. Then [Create your first migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs#create-your-first-migration).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov That's what I'm doing now. I'll stick with this approach then. thanks